# How do I install a Ubuntu on the cloud that can be accessed by any computer browser?

Tags: juju, cloud

I would like to install Ubuntu and eventually a virtual OS of windows inside Ubuntu in the cloud that can be accessed by any browser. In case I lose or damage my computer I wish not only to access Ubuntu by another computer but also run it's applications 24/7. Does Juju do this? Any suggestions or instruction manuals you can send me to implement this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juju only helps you here to fire up the instance with `juju deploy ubuntu`.

The other stuff you'd need to by hand for now unfortunately.